# C++ While Loop: Hex & Oct, & Dec

Tags: c++, loops

I'm currently working on a code that:

> takes 2 decimal numbers which are then displayed converted in octal, and hexadecimal, as well as in their original format, in a compact viewing table.

Currently, I'm restricted to a `while` loop. and the code looks like:

```
cout << "Enter in two hexadecimal numbers that will be the beginning and end\n";
while (num1 <= num2){
    // takes 2 hexadecimal inputs
    cin >> hex >> num1; cin >> hex >> num2; 

    cout << "Decimal\tOctal\tHexadecimal\n";
    cout << "***********************************\n";
```

It's not much, but this has been eating away at me for some time. I currently have no idea how to approach this.

Note: I don't know what to increment, or if I need another variable. If you could give advice, or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: It may help to think of it like this: "Octal" and "Hexadecimal" are not different kinds of integers, it's just a way of inputting/representing numbers. So, start with making a loop that iterates over the desired range and worry about output issues later on. You're nearly there!

Comment: If you have been helped by some of the answers, use the provided site facilities and accept it.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis This question is only 1 hour old... Generally it is a good idea to wait a day or two before accepting, unless one answer provides a good, complete answer and the asker doesn't care to see if someone might provide a better answer or point out problems in the current answers. But upvoting the good answers right away is a good idea.

Comment: To MrJsian, so what happens when you run your current program? Or, if you can't compile it, what compile errors you get? The basic way of solving these problems is to *run the code and see what it does*, and sooner the better. Work in small pieces, start with code which compiles and runs but does nothing, then expand on it. It's also much easier to ask about problems, when you have code which has just one problem, or one thing you don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you want to get your values, then loop from `num1` to `num2` with something like:

```
cout << "Enter in two hexadecimal numbers that will be the beginning and end\n";
cin >> hex >> num1; cin >> hex >> num2; //takes 2 hexadecimal inputs

while (num1 <= num2) {
    // ... do stuff
    ++num1;
}
```

Then you probably just want io manipulators as you used for input to output `num1` in your different bases in the "do stuff" part of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

One thing - you probably want to start the loop **after** you read the values

```
cout << "Enter in two hexadecimal numbers that will be the beginning and end" << endl;
cin >> hex >> num1; cin >> hex >> num2; //takes 2 hexadecimal inputs

while (num1<=num2)
{
   cout << num1 << "  " << oct <<  num1 << "  " << hex << num1 <<endl;
   num1++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this...

```
#include <iomanip>

.........

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
cout << "Enter number 1: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter number 2: ";
cin >> num2;

if(num1 > num2){
    cout << "number 1 needs to be smaller than number 2; exiting...";
    return 0;
}

cout << "Decimal\tOctal\tHexadecimal\n";
cout << "***********************************\n";
while(num1 <= num2){
    cout << dec << num1 << " " << oct << num1 << " " << hex << num1 << endl;
    num1++;
}
```

look into ios flags for c++

Comment: " I'm restricted to a While loop,"